# Http-proxy hangs up all the time

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, proxy

I have a JavaScript proxy server that often hangs up after having used it a while. This is the proxy code:

```
var express = require(["express"], function(){}),
    http = require(["http"], function(){}),
    port = (process.env.PORT || 8001),
    server = module.exports = express(),
    httpProxy = require(['http-proxy'], function(){});
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
// SERVER CONFIGURATION
// ====================
server.configure(function() {
  server.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.url.indexOf('/any/thing') === 0) {
      //console.log(res);
      proxy.web(req, res, {target: 'http://any.thing.com'});
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
  server.use('/anything', express["static"](__dirname + "/../public"));
  server.use(express.errorHandler({
    dumpExceptions: true,
    showStack: true
  }));
  server.use(express.bodyParser());
  server.use(server.router);
});
// Start Node.js Server
http.createServer(server).listen(port);
```

I am trying to do some tests with Nightwatch.js. The tests work up to a point, then the server crashes. In some tests this point is always reached at the same time, in others it depends when the server crashes and if it crashes at all.
This is the Error message:

> C:...\node_modules\http-proxy\lib\http-proxy\index.js:119
>
> > throw err;
> >
> > ```
> >      ^
> > ```
>
> Error: socket hang up
>
> > at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:215:15)
> >
> > at Socket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:247:23)
> >
> > at Socket.emit (events.js:129:20)
> >
> > at TCP.close (net.js:485:12)
>
> Stopping Express server

What could be the reason for this? I was not able to figure it out in google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is thrown when parallelly sending requests to the http-proxy.
The error can be prevented by installing a different version of http-proxy.
For me the error occured in http-proxy version 1.6.2.
I fixed the problem by installing version 1.0.0:

```
npm uninstall http-proxy
```

then

```
npm install http-proxy@1.0.0
```

Comment: Uhmm what's the evidence sir